# put multiple image-before-after section with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement before-after image comparison by jquery below.It takes two images and shows the comparison.

[fiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/napster91/m9jj2fsp/)

```
<div>
(image comparison1)
</div>

<div>
(image comparison2)
</div>

<div>
(image comparison3)
</div>
```

though it is very useful for me for single pair comparison, but the problem is whenever I want to implement the same effect with multiple pair, the container size defined in css becomes trouble. I have tried to make the width and height of css as auto & as fit to content, but nothing seems to work. **I want to implement multiple pair comparison on the same page as shown in div above.**

its like pairs of before after images.Each pair is of different size. Any suggeston for corrections with my coding is really appreciated.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: You will need to add your code to your question.

Comment: new section image gets overlapped on first section.

Comment: @Sirence if you click on fiddle. you will get the full working demo. take a look at the updated code : http://jsfiddle.net/m9jj2fsp/8/

Comment: Thank you, but it seems Jordums has answered your question already. You should click accept on his answer so the question gets closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching, this was the solution:

```
<div class="beforeAfterSlidebar" style="width:400px;height: 400px;">
    <div class="bottomImage"><img src="http://static13.jassets.com/p/Clarus-Urbane-Solid-Cotton-400-Tc-Satin-Double-Comforter-4656-990776-1-product2.jpg" width="400" height="400" alt="after" /></div>
    <div class="topImage"><img src="http://static13.jassets.com/p/Clarus-Urbane-Solid-Cotton-400-Tc-Satin-Double-Comforter-3369-201776-1-product2.jpg" width="400" height="400" alt="before" /></div>
</div>
<div class="beforeAfterSlidebar">
    <div class="bottomImage"><img src="http://upstairsweb.com/images/afterImage.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="after" /></div>
    <div class="topImage"><img src="http://upstairsweb.com/images/beforeImage.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="before" /></div>
</div>
```

With  the JS:

```
$(".topImage").css('width', '50%');
$(".beforeAfterSlidebar").mousemove(
function(e) {
  // get the mouse x (horizontal) position and offset of the div
  var offset =  $(this).offset();
  var iTopWidth = (e.pageX - offset.left);

  // set width of bottomimage div
  $(this).find(".topImage").width(iTopWidth);
});
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

*Old answers - but they might help others:*

I think you mean something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/m9jj2fsp/6/

I didn't use divs, but the images instead to create the effect:

```
<div class="beforeAfterSlidebar">
    <img id="topImg" src="http://upstairsweb.com/images/afterImage.jpg" width="800" height="600" alt="after" />
    <img id="middleImg" src="http://placehold.it/300" width="800" height="600" alt="middel"/>   
    <img id="botImg" src="http://upstairsweb.com/images/beforeImage.jpg" width="800" height="600" alt="before" />
</div>
```

The javascript to go with it:

```
  $(".beforeAfterSlidebar").mousemove(function(e) {
  // get the mouse x (horizontal) position and offset of the div
  var offset =  $(this).offset();
  var iTopWidth = (e.pageX - offset.left);

  // set width of bottomimage div
  $(this).children("#middleImg").css("clip", "rect(0px," +  (iTopWidth + 50) + "px,600px,"+(iTopWidth - 50) +"px)");
  $(this).children("#botImg").css("clip", "rect(0px," +  (iTopWidth - 50) + "px,600px,0)");
  });
```

If this isn't what you needed, just tell me, and I'll try to adapt my code.

Comment: your efforts are appreciated. thank you, But I wanted to implement something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/m9jj2fsp/7/  although i got my desired result,, but you can see that i have to write same code multiple times just with different width and height values which is very hectic for 10-12 image pairs.

Comment: Oh ok, I mis-understood your question completely, sorry. I thought you wanted more than to compare more than 2 images, instead of having more than 1 "compare-block".

Comment: still we can try to get a universal code for the bulk. take a look at : jsfiddle.net/m9jj2fsp/8

Comment: one step closer, thanks to you. How we going to solve this overlapping : http://jsfiddle.net/m9jj2fsp/13/

Comment: @NAPSTER no problem, I adapted my answer so it fits. Feel free to select it as "answered"